# running git reset --hard manually

Tags: git

Is there a way to perform the operations of `git reset --hard` manually -- either through direct bash commands, vim editing, or even just "lower-level" git commands?

EDIT: I removed many extraneous details unrelated to original question (which is probably why this was closed as too localized :) ).

Comment: Just type the command into a shell in your git repo - whats the problem?

Comment: I thought I said what the problem was in the question. sry if it was ambiguous. when I run the command directly, it gives an error. See edit.

Comment: Gut feeling free memory isnt the problem - whats the output from 'free'

Comment: You have 12Gb of RAM in you box - memory is not your problem

Comment: hmmm. You would think I would have bothered to notice that :) . Thank you for that input. If I get bored I'll track the problem down later.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git read-tree HEAD
$ git checkout `git diff --name-only`
```

this site was very helpful in figuring out what I needed to do: http://progit.org/2011/07/11/reset.html